# What package is this searchable file dialog a part of?

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, xfce, desktop-environment, dialog

I run a simple, basic system: arch linux with the i3 window manager. But my file save/open dialog is certainly quite fancy: [see this screenshot](https://db.tt/wsMLWis4). It dynamically updates and indexes the files as I start typing into it. It can make links and so on and so forth.

Does anyone know what package this is a part of? I think I've installed gnome, xfce or cinnamon when I was deciding between desktop environments and window managers a while ago. So it could be the remnants of any of those packages, but I can't tell which one it is.

Answer (score 1):

That's Gtk+'s [file chooser dialog](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserDialog.html). It's the `gtk3` package in Arch Linux.

Comment: So is gtk's file chooser dialog doing the indexing and searching? The file chooser appears to automatically search within subdirectories too, a feature I've not seen before.